# List to Node Tree (kinda)

Tags: c#

Given the following object:

```
public class Round 
{
   public Round Parent { get; set; }
   public int Depth { get; set; }
   public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

and the following code...

```
var rounds = new List<Round>();

var a1 = new Round { Depth = 0, Value = "a1" };
var b1 = new Round { Depth = 1, Value = "b1", Parent = a1 };
var c1 = new Round { Depth = 2, Value = "c1", Parent = b1 };
var b2 = new Round { Depth = 1, Value = "b1", Parent = a1 };
var a2 = new Round { Depth = 0, Value = "a2", };
var b2 = new Round { Depth = 1, Value = "b2", Parent = a2 };
```

Now I want to map this `List` to some kind of Node structure that looks like:

```
Node { 
    Value = "a1", 
    Depth = 0, 
    Nodes = Nodes[] { 
        Node { 
            Value = "b1", 
            Depth = 1, 
            Nodes = Nodes[] { 
                Node { Value = "c1", Depth = 2 } } },
        Node {
            Value = "b2",
            Depth = 1 } } }

Node {
    Value = "a2",
    Depth = 0, 
    Nodes = Nodes[] {
        Node {
            Value = "b2",
            Depth = 1 } } }
```

However I have absolutely no idea about how to map it.

Any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you just need to add a `Nodes` collection property to the `Round` class, or if you can't modify that class, create a Node-wrapper class for it:

```
public class Round 
{
   public Round Parent { get; set; }
   public int Depth { get; set; }
   public string Value { get; set; }
   public IList<Round> Nodes { get; set; }
}
```

In order to build the tree structure from the list of nodes, I'd use this strategy:

- sort the list by depth, ascending
- put all nodes in a hash set for quick reference
- build the tree in a single pass

Here's an example:

```
 // Assuming you have a NodeWrapper structure that wraps the Round objects
 public IList<NodeWrapper> BuildTrees(List<Round> list)
 {         
     Dictionary<Round, NodeWrapper> map = new Dictionary<Round, NodeWrapper>();

     List<NodeWrapper> roots = new List<NodeWrapper>();

     // order list and iterate through
     foreach(Round node in list.OrderBy(r => r.Depth))
     {
        NodeWrapper wrapper = new NodeWrapper(node);
        if(node.Depth == 0) {
            roots.Add(wrapper);                
        } else {
            var parentWrapper = map[node.Parent];
            parrentWrapper.AddChild(wrapper);
        }
        map.Add(node, wrapper);
     }

     return roots;
}
```

Comment: That would be an easy way around it, yea. But the thing is that this `Round` class is created deep inside an async method, and therefore doesn't allow it to be added as a child node, but only specifying it's parent.

Comment: Ohh.. I see what you're saying. You do need to create the node structure and then write a build tree method that takes the list and builds out the tree, or forest (if there are multiple root nodes).

Comment: Imagine the following: A crawler, that's doing thousands of async web requests. For each request it creates a `Round` object, and adds it to a thread-safe collection - at the same time it keeps an eye on, what `Round` object lead to the web request - this `Round` object is then set as the `Parent`. - This way it's impossible to have a `Nodes` collection for each `Round`, as I've no access to any previous added `Round` objects, but the `Parent`.

Comment: You mean you are trying to do this online? You still need to use some sort of structure to be able to back-reference your previous objects. If you need fast insert and retrieval then hashes and self-balancing trees are your friends.

Comment: No, not at all. Your answer is spot on! Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

If by `map` you mean print out like you've shown then what you need is something along the lines of a recursive `Print(List<Rount> nodes, Round curParent);` method, which prints out every node in `nodes` that have `curParent` as parent.

Call it initially with `null` for the `curParent` argument, and then call it recursively for each node you encounter.

Comment: By `map` I mean _transform_ the `List<Round>` into a `List<Node>` (or similar) with the structure given.

Comment: That is conceptually the same process except you need a node type that can hold a list of children.

Comment: `Map(List<Round> rounds, Round curParent, Node node)` ?

Answer (score 0):

How about converting it to an XmlDocument.  I blogged about a way to to that here:

http://weblogs.asp.net/stevewellens/archive/2009/01/01/from-table-to-treeview-displaying-hierarchies.aspx

You can ignore the part about displaying the hierarchy.